# Изменение раскладки строки SWIFT

Tags: строки, swift

Ситуация такая, нужно поменять раскладку строки, т.е, если у нас строка равна "qwer" , то нужно изменить её на "цук" , есть метод в Swift с помощью которого это можно сделать?

Comment: Нет готового метода. Раскладка клавиатуры слишком зависит от платформы, что ее делать частью стандартного SDK.

Comment: Нет такого, к сожалению (?). Только если через словарь самому делать